# django integrity error, i know why, but dont know how to solve

Tags: python, django, django-models, database-migration

I changed my former user model so that now it inherits from django's user model.

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class UserProfile(User):
 #fields..
```

but other models were pointing to my former model and now if i want to migrate, i am getting the error:

```
(user_id)=(9) does not exist in auth_user table.
```

reasonable error message. But what should i do now? i am really stuck. i am using **django version 1.4**

I made a screenshot of the error:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You don't say what version of Django you're using; if you're using 1.5, then you also need to set the `AUTH_USER_MODEL` setting to tell Django to use it (see the [auth docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model) for more info).  If you're on an earlier version, you probably don't want to subclass the User model at all, but create a profile (like your class name indicates) as a separate model and link it with a ForeignKey (see the [old profile docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/auth/#storing-additional-information-about-users) for more on that).

Did you also change the name of the model when you added the parent class?  You probably want to set the name of the table in UserProfile so that it matches the old name.  From the [Django model docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#table-names):

> To save you time, Django automatically derives the name of the database table from the name of your model class and the app that contains it. A model’s database table name is constructed by joining the model’s “app label” – the name you used in manage.py startapp – to the model’s class name, with an underscore between them.
>
> For example, if you have an app bookstore (as created by manage.py startapp bookstore), a model defined as class Book will have a database table named bookstore_book.
>
> To override the database table name, use the db_table parameter in class Meta.

So something like this would do the trick:

```
class UserProfile(User):
    # other stuff
    class Meta:
        db_table = "myapp_user"
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks Paul, great help. i thought, subclassing and putting foreign key are same thing. i am using django1.4